# how to check if user already exist in my controller

Tags: php

how to check if user already exist in my controller?

```
if ( isset($_POST['maakLid']) ) {
$gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
$wachtwoord = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST['wachtwoord']));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$console = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['console']);
$gamertag = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gamertag']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO leden (gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord, email, console, gamertag ) VALUES ('$gebruikersnaam','$wachtwoord','$email','$console','$gamertag')";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    $msg->add('e', 'Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw of contacteer een medewerker.','../registreren.php');
}




$msg->add('s', 'Je bent succesvol geregistreerd <strong>' . $gebruikersnaam . '</strong>. <br>Log nu meteen in om je skills te laten zien!','../index.php');
}

?>
```

I tried much but it all won't work

Comment: just create a select statement with a WHERE clause to check if that particular user already exists

Comment: i tried this but it wont work

`$checkuser = "SELECT * FROM leden WHERE gebruikersnaam = '$gebruikersnaam'";

 if ($checkuser) {
  $msg->add('e', 'Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw of contacteer een medewerker.','../registreren.php');
 }`

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you *have* already tried so we don't have to keep guessing/commenting. (ie edit/update your question with what you have tried, why it didn't work, what you want to happen, etc)

Comment: `$checkuser = "SELECT * FROM leden WHERE gebruikersnaam = '$gebruikersnaam'"; if ($checkuser) { $msg->add('e', 'Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw of contacteer een medewerker.','../registreren.php'); }` James

Answer (score 0):

```
//$_POST['input'] your unique input that you want to check that if already exist

$var = $_POST['input']

$query = "SELECT unique_thing FROM table WHERE unique_thing ='$var'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($query){
    echo "user existed";
}else{
    //do your insert operation
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried and it won't work..

`$gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
$checkuser = "SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM leden WHERE gebruikersnaam = '$gebruikersnaam'";
 $queryuser = mysqli_query($con, $checkuser);
if ($queryuser) {
  $msg->add('e', 'Er is iets mis gegaan.','../registreren.php');
 } else {





 $msg->add('s', 'Je bent succesvol geregistreerd <strong>' . $gebruikersnaam . '</strong>. <br>Log nu meteen in om je skills te laten zien!','../index.php');
}`

Comment: Everytime i get 'Er is iets mis gegaan.'

Comment: @NickdeKoning Can you not put "doesn't work" when someone is trying to help you? We do not know why it did not work. What did it do? What error did you get? HOW did it not work? We need more info than "doesn't work" otherwise we'll forever be posting guess code until it does work.

Comment: Your question states: "I tried much but it all won't work" Well, we've suggested *much* and that doesn't work either. So you need to edit your question, add details as to what you have tried, why it didn't work, what you want to happen, etc

Comment: @NickdeKoning maybe there is something wrong with your form.did you check that your $_POST variables gives your desired output?and did you check your database everytime you get Er is iets mis gegaan if its really inserted?